# Multiple inheritance in c++ with virtual functions

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

I have this code:

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void FA()=0;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual void FB()=0;
};

class Imp_A: public A
{
public:
   void FA()
   {
      // implement FA
   }
};

class Imp_B :public Imp_A, public B
{
   public:
       void FB()
       {
           // implement FB by calling FA()
           FA();
           // do some more work here.
        }
};
```

in class Imp_B, I don't want to implement FA as it is already implemented in Imp_A which this class is based.

But when I try to compile my code, I am getting error that Imp_B is virtual and can not be instantiated.

also when I try to call FA inside FB, I am getting error that FA is ambiguous.

How can I solve this problem?

Please note that Imp_A is based on A and implement it, Imp_B is based on Imp_A and B and the idea is that it uses implementation of A from imp_A and only implement B.

Comment: You're getting an ambiguous reference as it doesn't know whether to use class `A` or `imp_A`. To get around this you will need to prefix it with the base class you're wanting to implement it from so if you wanted to use class A then you would put `A::FA`.

You cannot instantiate virtual methods but you can ovverride them so you would need to specify that you're overriding the method. I haven't used C# in a while so I can't remember the exact syntax (hence why I'm commenting rather than answering).

Comment: @Vistari This is c++ and not c#. As FA is implemented in Imp_A, why I can not instantiate Imp_B?

Comment: @mtk99 This is not a duplicate of that question since here imp_A is based on A and on that question implementation has no relation to virtual class.

Comment: You are right, sorry

Comment: The actual error is that the call `FA();` is ambiguous (cannot decide between `A::FA` that came via `B`, and `A::FA` that came via `Imp_A`).   "Imp_B is virtual and can not be instantiated" is a cascade that should be ignored (it happened because the failure of `FA();` to compile means that `FB() { .... }` did not compile, so the class was not considered to have overriden the pure virtual definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the classic "diamond inheritance problem" where you have a virtual method defined in a base class which is inherited by two or more other classes which are used as source for multiple inheritance.

Anyway - virtual inheritance is the answer to your problem

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void FA()=0;
}

class B: virtual public A
{
public:
    virtual void FB()=0; //probably a pure virtual function as well!?
}

class Imp_A: virtual public A
{
public:
   void FA()
   {
      // implement FA
   }
}

class Imp_B :public Imp_A, public B //since you call FA() you need it's implementation from Imp_A
{
   public:
       void FB()
       {
           // implement FB by calling FA()
           FA();
           // do some more work here.
        }
}
```

The problem here is that Imp_b ends up with to definition for FA coming from two class A definitions; using virtual inheritance helps solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks, this did not solve the problem: Do you mean virtual public imp_A? Even this did not solved the problem. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: well, I compiled it here: http://cpp.sh/ and it compiles fine; mind that you have a typo in your original code FB() needs a return type.

Comment: I think you also need `class Imp_A: virtual public A`, and `class Imp_B: public Imp_A`.  Basically, everything that inherits A needs to inherit it virtually.

Comment: @Pandrei Can you please share your code on cpp.sh, so I can check it with my implementation?

Comment: @MartinBonner; not you don't Imp_A is not used in multiple inheritence and Imp_B does not need to inherit from imp_A it already has two class A definitions from A and B

Comment: @Pandrie:  If Imp_B doesn't inherit from Imp_A, how does it drag in the implementation of FA? (Which is what the OP is trying to achieve.)

Comment: @MartinBonner I stand corrected; I previously missed the fact that FA is a pure virtual function in A; Imp_B should inherit form Imp_A not A in this case.

Comment: @Pandrei O checked the code that you presented. If I try to instantiate Imp_B using this code inside main(): Imp_B bb; I am getting error which is exactly the error that I am getting.

Comment: @mans I just revised my answer; the previous version did not inherit the implementation for FA but rather the pure virtual function definition from A; now it should work: http://cpp.sh/7zcgu

Answer (score 2):

Your inheritance shema is more or less:

```
   Imp_B
   /   \
Imp_A   B
  |     |
  A     A
```

That means that you inherit from two different implementations of A. So `Imp_A::FA` is indeed defined but `B::A` is not, so the class `Imp_B` is still abstract. And it also explains the *error that FA is ambiguous*, because it could be either `Imp_A::FA` or `B::A`.

Ways to solve it:

- you could remove the inheritance `class B: public A`. That way `A` and `FA` will only exist in one branch and all will be defined
- you could make base class `A` virtual, meaning that only one instance will exist in `Imp_B`:

  ```
  class B: virtual public A
  ...
  class Imp_A: virtual public A
  ...
  ```

Comment: another solution is to explicitly indicate `Imp_A::FA()` (or `B::FA()`, if that one had a body)

Comment: @M.M: You are right for the part of calling FA in FB, but that would not solve the problem that Imp_B would still be abstract until it explicitely overrides B::FB

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about, `void FB()` in `Imp_B` overrides `virtual void FB() = 0;` in `B`

Answer (score 1):

```
class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual FB()=0;
}
```

You forgot to explicitly declare this as `void`, so this declares:

```
virtual int FB()=0;
```

And in `Imp_B` you declare:

```
void FB();
```

That doesn't work, of course. You didn't override anything there.

Comment: sorry, it was the type mistake in code, the original code that I have has void both on implementation and interface.